# Что сделать, чтобы не было undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const fetchFlight = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchFlight',
  async (code) => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://airlabs.co/api/v9/flight?flight_iata=${code}&api_key=...`
    );
    console.log(res.data);
    return await res.data.response;
  }
```

когда запрос как надо(${code} в запросе верный ),все работает.
но когда нет , сервер не отдаёт response так как попросту его уже нет,и соответственно идет udefined и не рендерится ничего ,как отловить ошибку ?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите перехватить ошибку, то можно добавить блок `catch()` для **axios**

```
export const fetchFlight = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchFlight',
  async (code) => {
    const res = await axios
      .get(`https://airlabs.co/api/v9/flight?flight_iata=${code}&api_key=...`)
      .catch((err) => { // Обрабатываем ошибку
        console.error(err);
        return {
          data: {
            response: // Тут то что должно отрендерится при ошибке
          }
        }
      })
    console.log(res.data);
    return await res.data.response;
  }
)
```

В самом блоке вы можете сами придумать, что возвращать и это станет вашей переменной `res`. Я, для примера, написал ожидаемую структуру ответа, туда можно положить значения по умолчанию, допустим или нули, тут уже вам решать.

Еще вариант, проверять, что же вернулось в ответе и уже исходя из этого отдавать тот или иной ответ:

```
export const fetchFlight = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchFlight',
  async (code) => {
    const res = await axio.get(
      `https://airlabs.co/api/v9/flight?flight_iata=${code}&api_key=...`
    )
    // если res.data.response undefined/null верни другое значение
    return res.data.response ?? { /* Ваш ответ при undefined/null */};
  }
)
```

Оба способа похожи, разница в том, что первый вариант сработает, если сервер ответит ошибкой, а второй будет всегда проверять значение на **undefined/null**

Ну и еще вариант, перед тем, как положить значение в состояние компонента, проверьте, что там что то есть. Если в ответе пусто, то, *например*, не выполнять обновление состояния:

```
// Если нет fetchFlight то не выполняй обновление состояния
if (fetchFlight) {
  setResponseToStore(fetchFlight)
}
```

Ну и в целом, функцию можно переписать так, что бы было более нагляднее и без лишних переменных

```
export const fetchFlight = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchFlight',
  async (code) => {
    return await axios
      .get(`https://airlabs.co/api/v9/flight?flight_iata=${code}&api_key=...`)
      .then(res => res.data.response) // Успешно, отдаем ответ
      .catch((err) => { // Ошибка! Обрабатываем и отдаем ответ
        console.error(err);
        return { data: { response: null } } 
      })
  }
)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам ,я уже сделал как 2 вариант...я начинающий,и не всегда хочу думать,главное ответ)

Comment: @Andrii зря не думаете, в дальнейшем аукнется. Вы должны понимать, что делаете и для чего

Comment: Да вот как раз я и подумал,и пришел к решению)А только потом заметил что есть ответ тут) но спасибо вам)